# ListView first Item overlaid

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

My `ListView` displays in first Item something else as the rest of the `ListView`

The Problem is, that it replaces the first item instead of taking a own position.

Example how it has to be:

> A (diferent to the others)
>
> B
>
> B
>
> B

How it is:

> A (B Overlaid by A)
>
> B
>
> B

As you can see, one B is missing because it is overlaid by A.

Here is the Code. I wrote my own CustomAdapter:

```
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (taskItems.size() + 1 >= 0)
        return taskItems.size();
    return 0;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView taskTitleTextView;
    public TextView taskObjectTextView;
    public TextView taskLocationTextView;
    public ImageView taskImageImageView;

}

public static class ViewHolderProjects {
    public TextView projectTitelTextView;
    public TextView projectInfoTextView;
    public TextView projectDeadline;
    public ImageView projectImageImageView;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolderProjects holderProjects;
    if (position == 0) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_projects, null);
            holderProjects = new ViewHolderProjects();

            holderProjects.projectTitelTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectTitle);
            holderProjects.projectInfoTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectInfo);
            holderProjects.projectImageImageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectImage);
            holderProjects.projectDeadline = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectdeadline);

            vi.setTag(holderProjects);
        } else {
            holderProjects = (ViewHolderProjects) vi.getTag();
        }
        if (projectMap.size() <= 0) {
            holderProjects.projectInfoTextView.setText("Keine Infos");
            holderProjects.projectTitelTextView.setText("Kein Titel");
        } else {
            if (projectMap.get(position).containsKey("project_company_image")) {
                if (projectMap.get(position).get("project_company_image").getBytes().length == 0) {
                    holderProjects.projectTitelTextView.setText(jobMap.get(position).get("job_subject"));
                    holderProjects.projectDeadline.setText(jobMap.get(position).get("job_deadline"));
                    return vi;
                }
                Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(base64EncodeDecode.decodeBase64(projectMap.get(position).get("project_company_image")));
                holderProjects.projectTitelTextView.setText(jobMap.get(position).get("job_subject"));
                holderProjects.projectDeadline.setText(jobMap.get(position).get("job_deadline"));
                holderProjects.projectImageImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
        }
    } else {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tasks, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.taskTitleTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.taskTitle);
            holder.taskObjectTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.taskObject);
            holder.taskLocationTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.taskLocation);
            holder.taskImageImageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.taskImage);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        if (taskItems.size() <= 0) {
            holder.taskTitleTextView.setText("Kein Titel");
            holder.taskObjectTextView.setText("Kein Objekt");
            holder.taskLocationTextView.setText("Kein Standort");
        } else {
            if (taskItems.get(position).containsKey("object_image")) {
                if (taskItems.get(position).get("object_image").getBytes().length == 0) {
                    holder.taskTitleTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("task_headline"));
                    holder.taskObjectTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("object_name"));
                    holder.taskLocationTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("object_location"));

                    return vi;
                }
            }
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(base64EncodeDecode.decodeBase64(taskItems.get(position).get("object_image")));
            holder.taskTitleTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("task_headline"));
            holder.taskObjectTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("object_name"));
            holder.taskLocationTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("object_location"));
            holder.taskImageImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
    return vi;

}
```

Comment: If i am not wrong....you want to add an extra element on top of list...which is not related to the list...is it correct?

Comment: yes absolutely correct

Comment: The correct way to add this extra item is to add it as a list header instead of forcing it to add through adapter which brings a lot of complexity.

Comment: can I load the header with informations from a hashmap?

Comment: Yes you can....just inflate your view and put the information in it...and set that view into the list header and make sure you do it before setting adapter to list.

Comment: Do you have an Example how to do this? What about a click event on the header? is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. First inflate your row layout into view:

   `LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();`

   `ViewGroup header = (ViewGroup)inflater.inflate(<R.layout.header>, myListView, false);`
2. Now you can take each component of view and can assign the values to them.eg:

   `TextView tv = header.findViewById(<R.id.text>);`
   `tv.setText("Something");`
3. Now just pass that header to the list view.

   `myListView.addHeaderView(header, null, false);`
4. To add listener to that header. Just pass a listnener to that view group:

   `header.setOnClickListener(<pass a new OnClickListener Instance>);`
5. After that you put the code to add adapter into list view.

   `myListView.setAdapter(<your adapter instance>);`

Answer (score 0):

If there is condition in inflating view in getView of CustomAdapter then you must 
override extra two methods..

declare a integer named "type" globally in adapter class

```
int type;
```

Override these two functions

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if(position == 0){
       return 0;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
    return super.getItemViewType(position);
}
```

Make a slight change to your getView function as given in the following code

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi = convertView;
    ViewHolderProjects holderProjects;
    type = getItemViewType(position);
    if (type == 0) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_projects, null);
            holderProjects = new ViewHolderProjects();

            holderProjects.projectTitelTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectTitle);
            holderProjects.projectInfoTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectInfo);
            holderProjects.projectImageImageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectImage);
            holderProjects.projectDeadline = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.projectdeadline);

            vi.setTag(holderProjects);
        } else {
            holderProjects = (ViewHolderProjects) vi.getTag();
        }
        if (projectMap.size() <= 0) {
            holderProjects.projectInfoTextView.setText("Keine Infos");
            holderProjects.projectTitelTextView.setText("Kein Titel");
        } else {
            if (projectMap.get(position).containsKey("project_company_image")) {
                if (projectMap.get(position).get("project_company_image").getBytes().length == 0) {
                    holderProjects.projectTitelTextView.setText(jobMap.get(position).get("job_subject"));
                    holderProjects.projectDeadline.setText(jobMap.get(position).get("job_deadline"));
                    return vi;
                }
                Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(base64EncodeDecode.decodeBase64(projectMap.get(position).get("project_company_image")));
                holderProjects.projectTitelTextView.setText(jobMap.get(position).get("job_subject"));
                holderProjects.projectDeadline.setText(jobMap.get(position).get("job_deadline"));
                holderProjects.projectImageImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
            }
        }
    } else {

        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_tasks, null);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.taskTitleTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.taskTitle);
            holder.taskObjectTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.taskObject);
            holder.taskLocationTextView = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.taskLocation);
            holder.taskImageImageView = (ImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.taskImage);

            vi.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) vi.getTag();
        }

        if (taskItems.size() <= 0) {
            holder.taskTitleTextView.setText("Kein Titel");
            holder.taskObjectTextView.setText("Kein Objekt");
            holder.taskLocationTextView.setText("Kein Standort");
        } else {
            if (taskItems.get(position).containsKey("object_image")) {
                if (taskItems.get(position).get("object_image").getBytes().length == 0) {
                    holder.taskTitleTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("task_headline"));
                    holder.taskObjectTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("object_name"));
                    holder.taskLocationTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("object_location"));

                    return vi;
                }
            }
            Bitmap bm = Bitmap.createBitmap(base64EncodeDecode.decodeBase64(taskItems.get(position).get("object_image")));
            holder.taskTitleTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("task_headline"));
            holder.taskObjectTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("object_name"));
            holder.taskLocationTextView.setText(taskItems.get(position).get("object_location"));
            holder.taskImageImageView.setImageBitmap(bm);
        }
    }
    return vi;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set header to `ListView` like this

```
View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.header_view, null, false);
listview.addHeaderView(headerView);
```

### Note: you have to set header view before setting the adapter